# Video free multi window size is not changed in android 7.1

Tags: java, android, android-video-player, start-activity, multi-window

I'm working on free multi window in **`android 7.1`**.

With test application free multi window is working perfect.(please fine screenshot 1)

[image]

Now Im playing video using MX player app, at that time free multi window size is not effecting.(please fine screenshot 2)

[image]

```
String mxPlayer = "com.xx.xx.ad";
    intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent1.setPackage(mxPlayer);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("http://xxx.75.135/Files/xxx/1_video/ideo.m3u");
    intent1.setDataAndType(videoUri, "application/mp4");
            startActivity(intent1, getActivityOptions(ApplicationType.CONTEXT_MENU).setLaunchBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 720, 512)).toBundle());
```

Could you please guide me to run video window size like attached image 1.